# Shortcut in Python for referrencing a class name within itself as an alias

Tags: python, class, static, alias

Let's say I have the following code:

```
class MySuperDuperLongClassName:
    var=1

    def printvar(self):
        print "MySuperDuperLongClassName.var is %d" % MySuperDuperLongClassName.var
```

And I want to write the print statement like this instead:

```
        print "Cls.var is %d" % Cls.var
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: just do `Cls = MySuperDuperLongClassName` in `printvar`. Tested and works

Comment: `Cls = MySuperDuperLongClassName` before that line might work. Never tried to alias the class name like that, but you never know.

Comment: Ok.  But let's say I want that in a pile of functions?

Comment: I should have included that detail originally...

Comment: @BuvinJ What do you mean? You could just have that as global if you need it in several places.

Comment: As a literal global outside my class? I guess... I could do that.

Comment: that's dirty. You have to initialize this global in the class itself (init method) first.

Comment: I have modules that have many classes in them which all have static members like this. I'd like a pattern to use in all of them, without naming a global like that something unique each time.

Comment: In the init? As an instance member? Then I need self.Cls

Comment: Definitely dirty, but if you need something accessed from multiple places, you'd need to have it in some broader scope. Having it as a class variable is a little better, but it's still a fairly globally accessible variable; just not one that's directly polluting the global namespace.

Comment: I'm going to use this in static functions btw, so I can't use an instance variable...

Comment: When saying `static functions` are you talking about `@staticmethod` or something else? If `@classmethod`, it can be accessed easiy.

Comment: Good point!  Yes, I mean `@staticmethod`.  I realize `@classmethod` would give me the `cls` argument.

Comment: The "best" solution I can think of is with is to use a private (i.e. __ prefixed), uniquely named module global...